# WCF wshttpbinding (SOAP 1.2) not working with SoapUI tool

Tags: soapui, wshttpbinding

I have simple WCF (.NET 3.5) Service application which has the default code created by VS 2008 when i open a new project.

I am having wshttpbinding with the following configuration in web.config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFTestServiceApp.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFTestServiceApp.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestServiceApp.IService1" bindingConfiguration="binding1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="binding1">          
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFTestServiceApp.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have run this WCF application and able to use VS 2008 WCFTESTCLIENT to send and recieve messages. 
I am not able to do the same with SoapUI tool. When i switch over to basichttpBinding it seems to work as its SOAP 1.1 version. But wsHttpBinding (SOAP 1.2) doesn't seem to work.

following is the reqest and response messages i receive in SoapUI tool.

**Request**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--type: int-->
         <tem:value>3</tem:value>
      </tem:GetData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">a:BadContextToken</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-IN">The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please advice how i should proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: replace wsHttpBinding with basicHttpBinding at <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestServiceApp.IService1" bindingConfiguration="binding1">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is because wsHttpBinding has integrated security by default.
Try this for disable security on WCF:

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="binding1">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
         <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: What if you prefer to have connection security? I think this answer is dangerous!